# Aggregation of "host" JSON object out of metricbeat on Elasticsearch

Tags: json, object, elasticsearch, aggregation, metricbeat

We are using metricbeat to collect lots of data (CPU, Memory, etc.).  Included are the "host" objects that look like this:

```
"_index": "metricbeat-7.4.2-2019.11.22-000001",
"_type": "_doc",
...
"host": {
  "id": "hostId1",
  "containerized": false,
  "name": "servername1",
  "hostname": "hostname1",
  "architecture": "x86_64",
  "os": {
    "kernel": "3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64",
    "codename": "Core",
    "platform": "centos",
    "version": "7 (Core)",
    "family": "redhat",
    "name": "CentOS Linux"
  }
```

There are many of these records created per day.  So I need to aggregate this host field and create output to tell me when the host configuration has changed.  Has there been an update to the OS?  Is there more RAM allocated today than yesterday?

I can write an aggregation to bin by id which looks like this:

```
"query": {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {"exists": {"field": "host"}},
                {'term': {'@timestamp': date}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_id": {
            "terms": {"field": "fields.id"}
        }
    }
```

and has output that looks like this:

```
'doc_count': 1677397,  'key': 'hostId1',
'doc_count': 1677397,  'key': 'hostId2'  (etc)
```

How can I instead aggregate on this "host" configuration object?  The goal would to return results like this:

```
{
    'doc_count': 900,  
    'id': 'hostId1'
    'key': {
         'host': {
             ...
             "hostname": "hostname1",
             "architecture": "x86_64",
             "os": {
                  "kernel": "3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64"
                  ...
              }
         }
     }
},

{
    'doc_count': 900,  
    'id': 'hostId1'
    'key': {
         'host': {
             ...
             "hostname": "hostname1",
             "architecture": "x86_64",
             "os": {
                  "kernel": "3.10.0-1102.4.3.el7.x86_64"
                  ...
              }
         }
     }
},
...
```

This output shows that the OS kernel was version "3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64" for 900 documents and "3.10.0-1102.4.3.el7.x86_64" for the rest.

Using this I'll be able to track these configuration changes on a daily basis without having to sift through the 9000 documents that metricbeat created that day.  The reason I this will work is that the host configuration should change very rarely so I can snag these aggregations and easily compare them.

I'm stuck.  No matter what I try it doesn't work.

How do I make something like this work?

```
"query": {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {"exists": {"field": "host"}},
                {'term': {'statDate': date}},
                {'term': {'fields.id': thisId}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "host": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "_source.host"
            }
        }
    }
```